# VMware and kernel 4.0

Tags: kernel, vmware

I'm trying to install VMware in Elementary OS freya updated with kernel 4.0 but it doesn't start. The error suggests incompatibility with kernel 4.0. How can I solve this?

Comment: You may need to recompile the virtualbox host modules against kernel 4.0, assuming the code is compatible. If it isn't, you may be out of luck, depending on your skillset. Also make sure the module is loaded, modprobe vboxdrv

Comment: Are you sure a VirtualBox package will help when trying to install VMware?

Answer (score 1):

Running the following vmware command with root privilege solved the problem for me:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```